# How to avoid using setTimeout to focus an anchor on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-safari

I've been using `setTimeout()` in order to set a focus on an anchor after a pop-up opens.

```
var openModal = function(e) {
    $popup.fadeIn('fast');
    setTimeout(function() {$closeModal.focus();}, 300);
    e.preventDefault();
};
```

And that way it works.

This way doesn't work:

```
var openModal = function(e) {
    $popup.fadeIn('fast', function() {$closeModal.focus();});
    e.preventDefault();
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to use the callback method of `fadein` ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey is not like the second function I posted? `$popup.fadeIn('fast', function() {$closeModal.focus();});`

Comment: @theUnnamed. second argument for fadeIn method in jquery accepts easing and third one is callback. Try to pass your function as the third argument and see if that works.

Comment: @VinodKolla the arguments are all optional and jQuery checks type so what you are suggesting is not necessary

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that we can run to reproduce the issue